# Склонение названия

Tags: склонение

Склоняется ли назвние фирмы, если оно указывается без кавычек. Например: сотрудники ООО Легион банка пошли обедать. Или правильно: сотрудники ООО Легион банк пошли обедать?

Comment: @Butyjina, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Для начала надо отметить, что в кавычки заключаются названия фирм, учреждений, организаций, обществ: гостиница "Россия", кондитерская фабрика "Красный Октябрь", ООО <<Компания "Металлинвест">>, ЗАО <<Издательский дом "Комсомольская правда">>. 
Названия учреждений, и организаций (в том числе магазинов) склоняются тогда, когда они употребляются ***(заметьте! без родового слова, а не без кавычек!)***. Напр.: ***конфеты "Красного Октября", премьера в "Современнике", издано "Наукой".***
Поэтому в приведенных вами примерах название фирмы  или, скорее всего, организации (поскольку вряд ли банк можно считать фирмой) не склоняется и должно быть заключено в кавычки.

> Корректно: ***сотрудники ООО "Легион банк" пошли обедать. Или: сотрудники "Легион банка" пошли обедать.***